# How to animate colors in an object in blender

Tags: blender, blender-2.61, blender-2.50, blender-2.67, blender-2.76

I was making an magic ball in blendeR.I have made the uv sphere ball already and also i have added 5-6 different colors with the help of light sources.Now i want the colors to animated or move in an jiggly way like whirl.Please see the link something like this :
http://luisbc.deviantart.com/art/Magic-Ball-II-364636015
I just want to make the colors inside my ball to move/circulate in a way.I don't know how to use Automatic Key Frame as well as how to make the lights move in a direction in my ball.
Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The basics of animation are -

1. Move to the frame that you want to specify a value.
2. Alter the value you want to animate.
3. Insert a keyframe for the value.
4. Repeat for other frames in the animation.

The [Automatic keyframe](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/timeline.html#keyframe-control) option can automate step 3 - but it will only add keyframes to values that have already been keyed. That means you have to manually add the first keyframe for a value, then as you change the value new keys will be created. Remember that it creates a keyframe on the current frame for the altered value so change frames before changing anything.

In blender almost any value can be animated, that could be the location and/or rotation of an object, the texture mapping values for a material or the colour of the material.

You can press <kbd>I</kbd> to add a keyframe, in the 3Dview this will show a list of common choices for location/rotation/scale and combinations of each. For values found elsewhere it will key the value located under the cursor. You can also right click on a value and select Insert Keyframe.

For help using blender you will find [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) a better place to ask for help.